# Selenium can't fire onchange on Select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

It's the first time I come across an issue with Select that Selnium webdriver couldn't fire the onchange on it.

The code is as usual:

```
Select country = new Select(driver().findElement(By.id("address.country")));
country.selectByValue("dk");
```

When the test runs, the country is selected successfully, at least on the interface, but when I click to submit the form, it says "Mandatory field is not filled in" and it hightlights at this country Select. When I manually click to choose a country, then it works.

I see this country Select has 3 events `blur`, `change` and `focus`. So I try to trigger it with Javascript after choosing a country as follow:

```
js().executeScript("arguments[0].onchange", country);
```

But it doesn't help as well. The front-end framework is Nuxt.js (vju)

Any thoughts? Thanks

---

**UPDATED**

Tried suggestion of @KonstantinPribluda, as the following check method, but it doesn't help as well

```
public Boolean isDropdownChanged(WebElement element) {
    WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)element).getWrappedDriver();

    return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("" +
            "var target = document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='address.country']\", document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null).iterateNext(); " +
                "   if(!target.disabled) {                  " +
                       "target.click();                     " +
                       "return true;                        " +
                    "}                                      " +
                    "return false;"
            , element);
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems that there is some kind of form validation which is not satisfied.   Maybe event was not propagated properly? Some frameworks have strange event handlers.   I had a lot of issues with JSF  and  delegating to  browser JS completely usually did the trick:   target = document.evaluate("whetever xpath selector you like", document.body,  null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null).iterateNext(); 
if(!target.disabled) { 
   target.click();  return true
}

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda: thanks for your suggestion. I converted your trick into a java method, but it doesn't help. I can't post my code in a comment, so I updated in my question.

Comment: I agree with @KonstantinPribluda. In some front-end frameworks the `select` dropdown is used only for display purposes. The actual functionality is built on top of the `select` tag as a 'facade'. This facade is what actual handles the triggering of events associated with the `select` dropdown. When you click the `select` tag, monitor the DOM (parent container, page footer, etc) for any new additions of HTML elements which act as a facade for the `select` dropdown. If yes, then you should trigger the `select` and then `click` or perform option related selection on the facade element.

Comment: @Ragnarsson  I would first debug javscript in browser tools to be sure -  I developed it for our JSF application  which has a lot of quirks (and recent update made it almost untestable -  because click was processed by  transparent overlay on top of dropdown  ) -  what are you using on frontend?

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda, this is new project, and we use Nuxt.js (vju)

Comment: Then just try javascript in browser console  and look if this  fires properly